# Problem with VoiceNext extension for Dsharpplus

Tags: c#, dsharp+

I've been having the issue, that when I use the "play" command on my bot (currently works only local using the path to the audio file) my bot sends a message
`An exception occured during playback: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified`
So far, I've tried finding an issue inside my code and aswell tried to find an answer online, but I couldnt find anything that could help
(as of writing my question, my code mostly consists of code from tutorials that I modified a bit)

main code:

```
using DiscordBot2.Commands;
using DSharpPlus;
using DSharpPlus.CommandsNext;
using DSharpPlus.EventArgs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DSharpPlus.Interactivity;
using DSharpPlus.Interactivity.Extensions;
using DSharpPlus.VoiceNext;

namespace DiscordBot2
{
    public class Bot
    {
        public DiscordClient Client { get; private set; }
        public CommandsNextExtension Commands { get; private set; }
        public VoiceNextExtension Voice { get; set; }

        public async Task RunAsync()
        {
            var json = string.Empty;

            using (var fs = File.OpenRead("config.json"))
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
                json = await sr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            var configJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConfigJson>(json);

            var config = new DiscordConfiguration
            {
                Token = configJson.Token,
                TokenType = TokenType.Bot,
                AutoReconnect = true,
                MinimumLogLevel = LogLevel.Debug,
            };

            Client = new DiscordClient(config);

            Client.Ready += OnClientReady;

            Client.UseInteractivity(new InteractivityConfiguration
            {
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
            });

            var commandsConfig = new CommandsNextConfiguration
            {
                StringPrefixes = new string[] { configJson.Prefix },
                EnableDms = false,
                EnableMentionPrefix = true,
                DmHelp = false
            };

            Commands = Client.UseCommandsNext(commandsConfig);

            Commands.RegisterCommands<FunCommands>();
            Commands.RegisterCommands<RoleCommands>();
            Commands.RegisterCommands<ModerationCommands>();
            Commands.RegisterCommands<MusicCommands>();

            Voice = Client.UseVoiceNext();

 
            await Client.ConnectAsync();

            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private Task OnClientReady(object sender, ReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

the code containing the music commands:

```
using DSharpPlus.CommandsNext;
using DSharpPlus.CommandsNext.Attributes;
using DSharpPlus.Entities;
using DSharpPlus.EventArgs;
using DSharpPlus.Interactivity;
using DSharpPlus.Interactivity.Extensions;
using DSharpPlus.VoiceNext;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DiscordBot2.Commands
{
    class MusicCommands : BaseCommandModule 
    {
        [Command("join")]
        [ Description("Joins a voice channel.")]
        public async Task Join(CommandContext ctx, DiscordChannel chn = null)
        {
            // check whether VNext is enabled
            var vnext = ctx.Client.GetVoiceNext();
            if (vnext == null)
            {
                // not enabled
                await ctx.RespondAsync("VNext is not enabled or configured.");
                return;
            }

            // check whether we aren't already connected
            var vnc = vnext.GetConnection(ctx.Guild);
            if (vnc != null)
            {
                // already connected
                await ctx.RespondAsync("Already connected in this guild.");
                return;
            }

            // get member's voice state
            var vstat = ctx.Member?.VoiceState;
            if (vstat?.Channel == null && chn == null)
            {
                // they did not specify a channel and are not in one
                await ctx.RespondAsync("You are not in a voice channel.");
                return;
            }

            // channel not specified, use user's
            if (chn == null)
                chn = vstat.Channel;

            // connect
            vnc = await vnext.ConnectAsync(chn);
            await ctx.RespondAsync($"Connected to `{chn.Name}`");
        }

        [Command("leave")]
        [ Description("Leaves a voice channel.")]
        public async Task Leave(CommandContext ctx)
        {
            // check whether VNext is enabled
            var vnext = ctx.Client.GetVoiceNext();
            if (vnext == null)
            {
                // not enabled
                await ctx.RespondAsync("VNext is not enabled or configured.");
                return;
            }

            // check whether we are connected
            var vnc = vnext.GetConnection(ctx.Guild);
            if (vnc == null)
            {
                // not connected
                await ctx.RespondAsync("Not connected in this guild.");
                return;
            }

            // disconnect
            vnc.Disconnect();
            await ctx.RespondAsync("Disconnected");
        }

        [Command("play")]
        [ Description("Plays an audio file.")]
        public async Task Play(CommandContext ctx, 
            [RemainingText, Description("Full path to the file to play.")] string filename)
        {
            // check whether VNext is enabled
            var vnext = ctx.Client.GetVoiceNext();
            if (vnext == null)
            {
                // not enabled
                await ctx.RespondAsync("VNext is not enabled or configured.");
                return;
            }

            // check whether we aren't already connected
            var vnc = vnext.GetConnection(ctx.Guild);
            if (vnc == null)
            {
                // already connected
                await ctx.RespondAsync("Not connected in this guild.");
                return;
            }

            // check if file exists
            if (!File.Exists(filename))
            {
                // file does not exist
                await ctx.RespondAsync($"File `{filename}` does not exist.");
                return;
            }

            // wait for current playback to finish
            while (vnc.IsPlaying)
                await vnc.WaitForPlaybackFinishAsync();

            // play
            Exception exc = null;
            await ctx.Message.RespondAsync($"Playing `{filename}`");

            try
            {
                await vnc.SendSpeakingAsync(true);

                var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "ffmpeg.exe",
                    Arguments = $@"-i ""{filename}"" -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1 -loglevel quiet",
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false
                };
                var ffmpeg = Process.Start(psi);
                var ffout = ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream;

                var txStream = vnc.GetTransmitSink();
                await ffout.CopyToAsync(txStream);
                await txStream.FlushAsync();
                await vnc.WaitForPlaybackFinishAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { exc = ex; }
            finally
            {
                await vnc.SendSpeakingAsync(false);
                await ctx.Message.RespondAsync($"Finished playing `{filename}`");
            }

            if (exc != null)
                await ctx.RespondAsync($"An exception occured during playback: `{exc.GetType()}: {exc.Message}`");
        }


    }
}
```

(The line of that gives the error message is at the bottom of the MusicCommands script)

```
 if (exc != null)
                await ctx.RespondAsync($"An exception occured during playback: `{exc.GetType()}: {exc.Message}`");
```

Comment: Do you know from what line of code the exception is thrown?  Can you [edit] your question to share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any?  There's a lot of code here and it's not immediately obvious where the problem might lie.  If you can narrow it down into a [mcve] it's more likely somebody will be able to provide an answer.  See also: [ask].

Comment: thanks for telling me, I added the line of code that tells the error at the bottom
. About the ```ToString()```, can you clarify what you exactly need? I dont quite understand which information is needed.
But still thanks